# How to get the list on anchor elements using protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, cucumberjs

I'm trying the get the list of link (anchor) elements under list. The code looks like:

```
+<div class="one" _ngcontent-c2="">
-<ul class="one" _ngcontent-c2="">
 -<li _ngcontent-c2="">
    <a href="#">Men</a>
  </li>
 -<li _ngcontent-c2="">
    <a href="#">Women</a>
  </li>
```

I tried the below script to get the values:

```
element.all(by.css('one li a')).each(function(element) {
    element.getText().then(function (text) {
       console.log(text); 
    }); 
});
```

But it throwing:

> NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, [type="text"])

error message.

Comment: element.all(by.xpath('//a'))

Comment: It'll bring all the anchor elements in the page rit... I need the anchor elements only present under <ul class="one"......

Comment: element.all(by.xpath('//ul[@class="one"]/a'))

Comment: One is class name. In CSS you have to put dot before class. You are missing dot here. Try with CSS like ".one li a"

Comment: Murthi is right but I would go one step further. Since you are looking for children and not descendants, add `>` to further restrict what is returned, e.g. `.one > li > a`. Your error message doesn't make sense given the code you posted. Please update your question with the current HTML, code, and error(s).